# pip install matplotlib error, error: /usr/local/man/man1/nosetests.1: Permission denied

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, pip, homebrew

I just had the following error when trying to install matplotlib using homebrew:

```
...[tons of output, then:]

running install_data

copying nosetests.1 -> /usr/local/man/man1

error: /usr/local/man/man1/nosetests.1: Permission denied

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/ys/l1bnz3cx34z3h4mrkny947v40000gr/T/pip_build_schultzm/nose/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/ys/l1bnz3cx34z3h4mrkny947v40000gr/T/pip-xWlPBu-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/ys/l1bnz3cx34z3h4mrkny947v40000gr/T/pip_build_schultzm/nose
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/schultzm/.pip/pip.log
```

I've been searching for an answer, could not find one.  However, I solved it (so posting it here for others) by doing:

```
sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/man/man1/
```

and then re-running the install (i.e., pip install matplotlib) and it ran fine.

Comment: it is explicitly encouraged to answer your own question http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

so could you please write down your solution for the problem in answers question? :)

Comment: I mean in answers section* sorry.

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/man/man1/
```

Then re-run the install (i.e., `pip install matplotlib`)

Explained: sudo allows admin privileges (allows 'super user' after entering an appropriate password), chmod allows the administrator to "change file mode", the '7' means (4[read] + 2[write] + 1[execute]), the first '7' means 'owner', the second '7' means 'group' and the third '7' means 'others'; so will allow admin privileges in order to make the change to the file mode to 'rwx' for owner, group and others.  The final part of the command is the file(s) you would like to chmod.

Comment: 777 is generally not something you want to do.

Comment: Revisiting this old question as someone recently upvoted the answer. I think it would probably work with `755` instead of `777`, because as @demongolem pointed out, `777` is not a good idea. AND, the question was asked about `brew install matplotlib`, but answered with `pip install matplotlib`. I recently tried, and only `pip install matplotlib` works, so I guess this whole thread is redundant. Should this question be deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Yep you are right. You have to change the permission.. If you have sudo permission then you don't need to change directory permissions.